# Dynamic 2D char array using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fgets, getline

I have the following code that can dynamically allocate a single sentece:

```
int  size=1;
char * text = (char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));

size = (int)sizeof(text);

fgets(text, si, stdin);

//remove new line()

printf ("Sentence = <%s>\n", text);
```

I would like to be able to allocate and store multiple lines ending in '\n' to further work with (format), I don't know how many lines I will be allocating or how long they will be. The input of lines ends with EOF. It doesn't have to be with fgets. 
For example:

- Sentence1\n
- Sentence2\n
  ....etc

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a char** declare a pointer to char pointers. Then you will have an array of strings.

Comment: @Supercan An Array is not a pointer...or you mean an Array of pointers ?

Comment: @ChuanzhenWu There is no such thing as `strings` in `C`, or `array of strings`.

Comment: @Michi sorry for the confusion. I am not talking about the exact string type because c doesn't have it. I am saying the char arrays.

Comment: @Michi Yes, use char* pointer to define a char* array, inside which every char pointer is used to point to a char array.

Comment: @ChuanzhenWu You mean `char *pointer[SIZE]` or `char *pointer` ?

Comment: @Michi Exactly. But instead you can use 'malloc' to dynamic initialize your char pointer array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97730/discussion-between-michi-and-chuanzhen-wu).

Comment: @Supercan In `C` there is no reason to `cast` `malloc`, because its return type is void*, and there is no reason to `cast` `sizeof` to int with that approach. Just use `size_t  size=1;` instead of `int  size=1;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the classic question of how do I handle dynamic allocation and reallocation to store an unknown number of strings. It is worth understanding this process in detail as it will serve as the basis for just about any any other circumstance where you are reading an unknown number of values (whether they are structs, floats, characters, etc...).

There are a number of different types of data structures you can employ, lists, trees, etc., but the basic way (as you call it *"2D char array"*) is handled by creating an array of *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* (with *type* being `char` in this case) and then allocating space for, filling with data, and assigning the starting address for the new block of memory to each pointer as your data is read. The short-hand for *pointer-to-pointer-to-type* is simply *double-pointer* (e.g. `char **array;`, which is technically a *pointer-to-pointer-to-char* or *pointer-to-char** if you like)

The general, and efficient, approach to allocating memory for an unknown number of lines is to first allocate a reasonably anticipated number of pointers (1 for each anticipated line). This is much more efficient than calling `realloc` and reallocating the entire collection for every line you read. Here, you simply keep a counter of the number of lines read, and when you reach your original allocation limit, you simmply reallocate twice the number of pointers you currenly have. Note, you are free to add any incremental amount you choose. You can simply add a fixed amount each time, or you can use some scaled multiple of the original -- it's up to you. The *realloc to twice current* is just one of the standard schemes.

When allocating your pointers originally, and as part of your reallocation, you can benefit by setting each pointer to `NULL`. This is easily accomplished for the original allocation. Simply use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. On reallocation, it requires that you set all new pointers allocated to `NULL`.

Why? It isn't mandatory, but doing so allows you to iterate over your array of pointers without knowing the number of lines. How does that work? Example, suppose you initialized 100 pointers to `NULL` and have assigned a number of lines to each pointer as you go. To iterate over the collection you can simply do:

```
size_t i = 0;
while (array[i]) {
    ... do your stuff ...
}
```

Only pointers you have assigned something to will have a value. So the loop will only interate over the pointers that have a value, stopping when the first `NULL` pointer is encountered. (the first `NULL` simply serves as your *sentinel* value telling you when to stop). This also provides the ability to pass a pointer to your collection to any function without also passing the number of lines/values contained. (*note:* there is no reason not to pass the size of the collection, but there are circumstances where this is a benefit)

The example below uses the traditional approach of iterating over a fixed number of lines to print the lines, and then free the memory allocated, but there is no reason you couldn't simply iterate over the valid pointers in both cases to accomplish the same thing.

The same holds true when allocating storage for your lines as well. If you use `calloc` instead of `malloc`, you initialize all values to `0` (`nul`). The storage for all your strings is then guaranteed to be *nul-terminated* by virtue of the initialization. The same applies to allocating for numeric arrays as well. By initializing all values to `0` you prevent any possibility of an accidental attempted read from an uninitialized value (undefined behavior). While generally not a problem when you sequentially fill/read from an array, when randomized storage and retrieval routines are used, this can be a real problem.

When allocating memory, you must validate that each call succeeded (e.g. for `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and for other function calls that allocate for you like `strdup`). It is just a simple check, but it is something to get in the habit of doing every time or risk attempted reads and writes from/to unallocated memory. In the example below, simple functions are used as a wrapper for `calloc` and `realloc` that provide the necessary checks. While there is no requirement to use similar helper-functions, they help keep the main body of your code free from repetitive memory checks, etc. that can make the code more difficult to read.

A final note on `realloc`. *Always* use a temporary variable to hold the return of `realloc`. Why? On success `realloc` returns a pointer to the newly allocated block of memory. On failure it returns `NULL`. If you fail to use a temporary pointer and the request fails, you have lost access to (lost the address of) all of your previously stored values. Once you validate `realloc` succeeded, simply assign your temporary pointer to the original.

The example below will read all lines from the filename given as the first argument to the program (or `stdin` by default). It uses `fgets` to read each line. Each line is tested to insure that all characters in the line were successfully read. If the line was too long to fit into the space provided, a simple warning is given, and the remainder is read into the following line of storage (you can `realloc` and concatenate here as well). All lines are stored in `array`. There are `MAXL` (64) pointers originally allocated and each line can hold `MAXC` (256) characters. You can change either to meet your needs or set `MAXL` to `1` to force the reallocation of lines to begin there. The lines are simply printed to the terminal, and then all memory is freed before the program exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256    /* max chars per-line */
#define MAXL  64    /* initial num lines  */

void *xcalloc (size_t n, size_t s);
void *xrealloc_dp (void *ptr, size_t *n);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char **array = NULL;
    char buf[MAXC] = {0};
    size_t i, idx = 0, maxl = MAXL;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    array = xcalloc (maxl, sizeof *array);    /* allocate maxl pointers */

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))  /* read all lines from fp into array */
    {
        size_t len = strlen (buf);

        /* validate complete line read */
        if (len + 1 == MAXC && buf[len - 1] != '\n')
            fprintf (stderr, "warning: line[%zu] exceeded '%d' chars.\n",
                    idx, MAXC);

        /* strip trailing '\r', '\n' */
        while (len && (buf[len-1] == '\n' || buf[len-1] == '\r'))
            buf[--len] = 0;

        /* allocate & copy buf to array[idx], nul-terminate
         * note: this can all be done with array[idx++] = strdup (buf);
         */
        array[idx] = xcalloc (len + 1, sizeof **array);
        strncpy (array[idx], buf, len);
        array[idx++][len] = 0;

        /* realloc as required (note: maxl passed as pointer) */
        if (idx == maxl) array = xrealloc_dp (array, &maxl);
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);

    printf ("\n lines read from '%s'\n\n", argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin");
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        printf ("   line[%3zu]  %s\n", i, array[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        free (array[i]);    /* free each line */
    free (array);           /* free pointers  */

    return 0;
}

/* simple calloc with error checking */
void *xcalloc (size_t n, size_t s)
{
    void *memptr = calloc (n, s);
    if (memptr == 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xcalloc() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memptr;
}

/*  realloc array of pointers ('memptr') to twice current
 *  number of pointer ('*nptrs'). Note: 'nptrs' is a pointer
 *  to the current number so that its updated value is preserved.
 *  no pointer size is required as it is known (simply the size
 *  of a pointer
 */
void *xrealloc_dp (void *ptr, size_t *n)
{
    void **p = ptr;
    void *tmp = realloc (p, 2 * *n * sizeof tmp);
    if (!tmp) {
        fprintf (stderr, "xrealloc_dp() error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    p = tmp;
    memset (p + *n, 0, *n * sizeof tmp); /* set new pointers NULL */
    *n *= 2;

    return p;
}
```

**Compile**

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/fgets_lines_dyn fgets_lines_dyn.c
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_lines_dyn dat/captnjack.txt

 lines read from 'dat/captnjack.txt'

   line[  0]  This is a tale
   line[  1]  Of Captain Jack Sparrow
   line[  2]  A Pirate So Brave
   line[  3]  On the Seven Seas.
```

**Memory Leak/Error Check**

In any code your write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 responsibilites regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) always preserves a pointer to the starting address for the block of memory so, (2) it can be freed when it is no longer needed. It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you haven't written beyond/outside your allocated block of memory and to confirm that you have freed all the memory you have allocated. For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are so many subtle ways to misuse a block of memory that can cause real problems, there is no excuse not to do it. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use. Just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/fgets_lines_dyn dat/captnjack.txt
==22770== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22770== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22770== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22770== Command: ./bin/fgets_lines_dyn dat/captnjack.txt
==22770==

 lines read from 'dat/captnjack.txt'

   line[  0]  This is a tale
   line[  1]  Of Captain Jack Sparrow
   line[  2]  A Pirate So Brave
   line[  3]  On the Seven Seas.
==22770==
==22770== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22770==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22770==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 1,156 bytes allocated
==22770==
==22770== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22770==
==22770== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22770== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Simply look for *All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible* and *ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts*. If you don't have both, go back and figure out why.

This ended up much longer than anticipated, but this is something worth understanding. Let me know if there is anything else you have questions on.

Comment: Wow, this is a very comprehensive answer. Some remarks: Growing (`realloc()`ating) by a constant amount is a bad idea as it will have quadratic complexity instead of amortized linear. Growing by any constant *factor* greater than 1 is fine, tough. You can use 3/2 if 2 seems like too much. I'm not sure I agree with the zero-initialization recommendation. If you're going to read bytes into the array anyway, I think filling it up with zeros before is just a waste of time. If available, [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) will be very useful.

Comment: Just curious: What was it that you disliked about me removing C syntax highlighting from text that was not C source code?

Comment: It must have got caught in one of my edits. I was editing and it asked me to revert and I clicked yes. Sorry. It wasn't intentional. And yes, there are `+/-`'s on the `calloc`, `malloc` issue. It's political at that point. I've tested over `100,000,000` iterations of `malloc` verses `calloc` and the difference is negligible`. I use a mix of either when I'm writing, but for answers, I like to point out the benefits of zeroing. Then the OP can figure out which camp he falls into.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin   One more question, when i compile "gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/fgets_lines_dyn fgets_lines_dyn.c**pp**", it gives me various [-fpermissive] errors "invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘char**’ ". Does this have to do with casting?

Comment: Glad we could help. There are is a lot to learn with C. Probably the biggest is simply to *s l o w d o w n* and take time to really understand and learn the basics. Two of those basics are pointers, and dynamically allocating using and freeing memory. You can tell if you are learning. If you are searching for a function that may fit your need, it's time to slow-down, you need to learn a little more to be comfortable *knowing* what functions are available and choosing between those available to meet your particular coding need. If you find yourself chasing the 1st, stop, learn and use the 2nd.

Comment: For your error, what compiler version are you using? and Why are your files named `*.cpp` (that is usually for C++). Make all files have the `.c` extension and try again. Also, check if the warning regarding the `void*` type has to do with `realloc_dp` function. I'll show you how to fix that if that is what it is. If you want to check try `array = (char **)xrealloc_dp ((void *)array, &maxl);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Using `array = (char **)xrealloc_dp ((void *)array, &maxl);` worked. I am using _gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)_. I work in NetBeans 8.0.2 and i assumed that the extention of the file does not really matter since it says im creating a C/C++ Application.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you compile with the *Warnings Enabled*, the compiler should have shown warnings regarding the types expected. If you look at the `xrealloc_dp` function, it handles a `void` type, meaning it will provide reallocation for *Any* type double-pointer (which makes sense since a pointer-is-a-pointer-is-a-pointer). The file extension does have some impact on some of the default compile/pre-processor behavior (I don't know precisely what), but I would not recommend using a `.cpp` extension for plain C files.